# Include tarball instead of zip file from Github in Zenodo

Tags: github, zenodo

I maintain a few (Unix) repositories on Github where I autolinked the releases to Zenodo. It turns out that Zenodo only takes the Zip files, not the tar balls. In my case this is bad, since the zip files mess up symbolic links at least with the GUI of MacOS.

How can I instruct Zenodo to actually use the tar ball and not the zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`zenodo/zenodo` `zenodo/modules/github/api.py`](https://github.com/zenodo/zenodo/blob/a806d10700a504cc86abaf9eb961dc201b3d8fe8/zenodo/modules/github/api.py#L35) code, releases are managed by the third-party dependency library [`inveniosoftware/invenio-github`](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/invenio-github).

[`inveniosoftware/invenio-github` `invenio_github/models.py#create()`](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/invenio-github/blob/7d3678c81e8d4f8f60023f0832d6166998c53412/invenio_github/models.py#L312-L337) does create a release, which, [from this](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/invenio-github/blob/7d3678c81e8d4f8f60023f0832d6166998c53412/invenio_github/templates/invenio_github/settings/index.html#L75), seems only to consider zip archives.

So this is not yet supported.